# Does APE (Ajax Push Engine) require the web browser to be open before it can function?

Tags: ajax, browser, telnet, terminal-emulator, ape

I have a program that runs in a terminal emulator (Telnet) and I need a way to open websites from it. I've been exploring making an app that listens to a network port for XML from the telnet session and launches whichever website it asks for. Is that something and APE server could do, or does APE only run in an existing browser?